# saving Image using sql query method

Tags: java, android

I am using following code: Note that i HAVE TO SEND SQL Query so using this procedure.

`currentReceipt.image` is a `byte[]`

```
       String updateQuery = "INSERT INTO MAReceipts(userId, transactionId, transactionType, receiptIndex, referenceNo, image, smallThumb, comments, createdOn, updatedOn) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

       java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
   long t = today.getTime();
   java.sql.Date now = new java.sql.Date(t);

   for(int i = 0; i < receipts.size(); i++)
       {
        try{
       Receipt currentReceipt = receipts.get(i);
           String[] valVars = {
                    stringToDB(transaction.userId), 
                    integerToDB(transaction.transactionId),
                    integerToDB(transaction.transactionType.getValue()),
                    integerToDB(i),
                    stringToDB(currentReceipt.referenceNo),
                    (currentReceipt.image != null ? imageToDB(currentReceipt.image): "null"),
                    (currentReceipt.smallThumb != null ? imageToDB(currentReceipt.smallThumb): "null"), // NEED TO CHANGE THIS TO SMALL THUMB
                    stringToDB(currentReceipt.comments),
                    dateToDB(now),
                    dateToDB(now)
                    };

            mDb.execSQL(updateQuery, valVars); 
        }catch (Exception e){
           Log.e("Error in transaction", e.toString());
           return false;
            }
       }


public String imageToDB (byte[] image)
    {
      String convertedImage = image.toString(); 
      return convertedImage;
    }
```

`return convertedImage` shows a value of `[B@43eb4218` or similar to that.

Now this data is saved in database. Please tell me is the image is correctly saving in database and can i retrieve it? If not then any preferable way , do tell me.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing an image in SQLite is not a good idea. You should save the image on SD card and store its path in database.

Anyhow, if you still want to store the image in database, then you need to do the following:

1. Convert image into bytes
2. Convert bytes into `Base64` encoded string
3. Save the Base64 encoded string into database

**Reversing the process will give the image.*

Another solution is to convert your column **smallThumb** type to `BLOB` and store the bytes directly. But for this you need to modify your table.

---

In your code, change the method **imageToDB** as below:

```
public String imageToDB (byte[] image){
    return Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
}
```

Comment: Simply by getting the Base64 string from database and then `byte[] image = Base64.decode("Base64StringfromDatabase", Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: Base64 is not being recognized by eclipse as anything.

Comment: did you import `import android.util.Base64;`? Its available in android framework, so there's no chance that you cannot access it. Fix your imports

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store image in database you must use BLOB.

SQL:

```
"CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ....., IMAGE_COLUMN BLOB)";


public void save(..., byte[] image ,...) {
    ......
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("ID", ...);
    .....
    values.put("IMAGE_COLUMN", image);
     .....
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better store the image path instead of the image data inside the database.

When you retrieve the data, just load the image from the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a horrible practice.

Furthermore, this is the real format

```
mDb.execSQL(updateQuery, Object[] arg); 

public Object imageToDB (byte[] image){
    return (Object )image;
}
```

Change the type of `String valVar[] to Object valVar[]`.. It will store the image as byte blob.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use your method `byte[] -> string to save to database`, you need do follow to get:

```
    String str = get from your database;
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
    Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```